# Locating Apache source code for mod_perl on Mac

Tags: apache, macos, mod-perl

I get the following error in Terminal when I try to install mod_perl:

> Please tell me where I can find your apache src
>
> [../apache_x.x/src]

I've tried using cpan > install mod_perl(even forcing v. 2) AND I've tried just downloading it, and doing `$ perl Makefile` but they both lead to the same error.

I'm trying to follow steps from http://bulknews.net/lib/mod_perl_guide/install.html or Oreilly's CGI Programming with Perl but the site says:

> The first thing first is to download the Apache source code and unpack it into a directory -- the name of which you will need very soon

Mac comes with Apache, which is why I don't want to download it. But how can I find the apache src???

Update: Haven't checked, but did find apache2 folder in ~/private/var/log

---

Additional Info --- separate locations of mod_perl files:
I have an unzipped folder: mod_perl-1.31 in my ~/Downloads folder. (for manual install)

I found tar.gz files of mod_perl -1 and -2 in ~/G/GO/GOZER/mod_perl-1.31.tar.gz (or 2.04) (for cpan)

Should I delete these?

Let me know if there is any other info required to solve this, or if I somehow missed a post with this same question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That bulknews webpage is *very* old. Things have changed since 2001. What version of Apache do you have installed?

Comment: Do you mean installed from online, or the one that comes with the Mac?? I downloaded all kinds from online, should I just put them somewhere and answer the error with that folder? Where would suggest? Not sure where to check the Mac version, but as I said, there is a folder apache2, so I'd guess it's that

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that Mac OS X doesn't ship with the apache source code (I'll be damned if I can find it.)  I can find no references to it online or on my machine.

I am going to ignore the built-in Apache installation and install my own.  This article discusses PHP and Apache on Mac OS X but I'll also be using mod_perl on my system and will adjust as necessary: http://www.phpied.com/installing-php-and-apache-on-mac-osx-that-was-pretty-easy/

Answer (score 0):

Install it dynamically as a dso.

https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/install/install.html#Dynamic_mod_perl